# Multiple authentications to Sharepoint when running Power Queries in Excel

Tags: excel, authentication, sharepoint

The Power Queries in an Excel workbook get data from an Excel worksheet stored on Sharepoint, a Sharepoint list and from Project Online on the same Sharepoint site. Each data source type prompts the user for authentication separately (the logo in the dialog changes to reflect the data source type). All authentications are made against the root of the Sharepoint site. Is this an issue with config or a Sharepoint "feature"?

Answer (score 0):

Asking credentials is the feature of Power Query. Credentials are distinguished based on at least url of the source you choose when set the credentials. So if you choose different URLs for your sources, you'll have to set up credentials for every source, even if they are on the same site.